# How to resolve data flow interruptions due to Flink Backpressure (max):100%?

Tags: apache-flink, backpressure

I am currently using Kafka and Flink in conjunction, where I read data from Kafka, process it in Flink using SQL, and then send it back to Kafka.

The issue I'm facing is that Flink operates well initially, but after a while, Backpressure occurs, causing the processing to come to a halt.

I would like to know if there are any settings or configurations available to ensure a smooth flow of this pipeline.

- Captured web screen when an issue (Backpressure(max):100% - Busy(max):100%) occurred.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq8vL.jpg)
- The SQL query corresponding to Busy(max) is this one

```
    SELECT last.Did, split.Sid
         FROM (
            SELECT Did, rowtime, Sid 
            FROM (
               SELECT Did, Sid, rowtime, ROW_NUMBER() 
               OVER (PARTITION BY Did ORDER BY rowtime DESC) AS numrow 
               FROM composition
             ) 
             WHERE numrow = 1
          ) as last CROSS JOIN UNNEST(last.Sid) AS split (Sid)
```

I attempted clustering, but the issue has resurfaced once again

It seems like the SQL query needs normalization, and I need assistance with that.